# Image button OnClientClick() event issue in ASP.net using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am having one Web page(First window). In that page I am having one image button, Which is having OnClientClick event. In that event I call a javascript method as `OpenHelpWindow()` i.e.

```
OnClientClick ="OpenHelpWindow()"
```

Now whenever I clicked that image button the event in the javascript method`(OpenHelpWindow())` will get trigger and it will open the New help web window. Its working properly but the problem is, When I press Enter key then also the event will get fire and show me the help window.
 Now I want to stop the second window (Help window) opening when the Enter key pressed.

How can I resolve this problem?

My Code for the first web window Image button is,

## .aspx code

```
.
.
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/help.png" runat="server" ID="ibtnHelp"
                                AlternateText="Help" ToolTip="Help"  OnClientClick="OpenHelpWindow()" />
.
.
```

## Javascript code for OpenHelpWindow() is

```
function OpenHelpWindow()
{
var newWin = null;
try
 {
    newWin = window.open("../Common/OpenHelpUrl.aspx");
    newWin.focus();
    return false;
 }
finally
 {
    newWin = null;
 }
}
```

Comment: is this your default button?

Comment: @Prasad: Default button means, What do u mean?

Comment: see below ans of Roy Dictus!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ImageButton` is the form's default button, which means that when the user presses Enter, that button automagically gets "pressed". This is standard ASP.NET behavior.

You can change this by adding the following attribute to your `<ImageButton.../>` tag:

```
UseSubmitBehavior="False"
```

Good luck!

**EDIT**

If this doesn't work (which it should!), then you can fool the browser by adding an invisible dummy button in your form:

```
<asp:Button ID="dummy" runat="server" Text="" OnClientClick="return false;" style="display:none;"/>
```

and then adding `defaultButton="dummy"` to your `<form />`.

Comment: I added this on my Image button tag but Still its opening that help window when I am pressing Enter key.

Comment: Have you specified `defaultButton = "ibtnHelp"` in your `<form>` tag or in code anywhere?

Comment: No I didnt specified defaultButton="ibtnHelp" anywhere in my application. I dont know How it could be acting as a default button? Please help me on this.

Comment: I've added something to my answer, check above.

Comment: Thanks for your nice code.I think, This should work. Will apply this on my code and let you know about it.

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer so that everyone knows this question was answered. Thank you!

Comment: Roy, I am having one more doubt. I am using this image button for arroud 40 pages so I have to modify 40 pages.Instead of modifying these 40 pages, can we set the default button as a common place like WEB.CONFIG file?

Comment: Fine , Can we have do this as a common using some another way?

Comment: I think some of the confusion was that `asp:Button` has `UseSubmitBehavior`, but `asp:ImageButton` does not have this property.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: how does this answer the question?