# Inmage button Onclient click issue vb.net

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, imagebutton

I am having a web Page. On clicking a button (Savebutton) it should save that changes. But before saving i want to display an warning message. And then save the changes. My current code is displaying the message but even if i click on enter key without clicking on 'Ok' its saving. Can anyone suggest any other solution. I want to use RadWindow for the alert.

My Code for the Image button.

```
 <asp:Panel ID="SavePnl1" runat="server" Visible="False">
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: right; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
       <asp:ImageButton ID="SaveBtn1" runat="server"
               AlternateText="Save " ImageUrl="~/images/icons/save_sml.png" OnClientClick="saveclick()" />
    </div>
 </asp:Panel>
```

Javascript:

```
function saveclick()
  {
      window.alert('Check the users before saving'); 
 }
```

I tried this link '[Image button OnClientClick() event issue in ASP.net using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232731/image-button-onclientclick-event-issue-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp)' but didnt understood it clearly.

Thanks

Comment: Why you need return true after the saveclick() function?

Comment: I was just trying to check what is happening

Comment: Remove it and try you will get alert window

Comment: Even if i remove it and press enter key its saving

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when you press enter key the function shouldn't be called . right?

Comment: Only when i click on "Ok" and nothing should happen on pressing enter key

Comment: I would suggest you a lame solution which must work. Just set the tab index to 1 since the tab index of image button is 0, on pressing enter the button is hit, so set it to other than 0

Answer (score 0):

Adding a dummny button resolved the issue .

```
<asp:Panel ID="SavePnl1" runat="server" Visible="False">
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: right; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="SaveBtn1" runat="server"
             AlternateText="Save " ImageUrl="~/images/icons/save_sml.png" OnClientClick="saveclick()" />
   </div>
    <div  style="display: none">
       <asp:Button ID="FinalSaveBtn1"  runat="server" Text=""  />
  </div>
```